# How do relativistic effects lead to gold not usually occuring in a 2+ oxidation state?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, physical-chemistry

In the literature I found compounds where gold occurs in a 1+ and 3+ oxidation state, like the perovskite CsAuCl_3, and also came across the fact that gold usually doesn't occur in a Au2+ state. However, I'm struggling to find a good explanation for this.

My current understanding is that gold ([...]6s1, 5d10) simply is a very large atom and that the 1+ state is pretty stable due to the completely empty 6s shell and the 3+ state has a d8 configuration in which all electrons are paired up with another one of the opposite spin (violating Hund's rule, but apparantly this is quite common in heavier elements). Then, since gold is so large, the outmost d orbitals are pretty delocalized and therefore make the gold2+ configuration unstable.

I've also read arguments involving relativistic effects of the s-p-shells pushing out the other orbitals, making them more delocalized, but all of this just sounds very hand-wavy to me. Maybe someone can provide me with a better answer. Thank you!